# Excel Macro save as xlsx

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, xlsx

I need to save several workbooks as xlsx instead of PDF but I forgot how to get it back to save as excel also can I specify where to save on my computer?

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Range("B2").Value & " March 2021  List" _
, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Comment: Did you try using [`Workbook.SaveAs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas), which has the *FileName* and *FileFormat* parameters?

Comment: would that look something like  



 `Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
        Filename:="C:\Users\rawdata\Desktop\Files\" & CStr(UListValue) & " Insert Text Title Here" & ".xlsx" _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

Comment: It would be best to also specify the *FileFormat*.

Comment: Use the macro recorder, and adapt the path